# Open excel link with vba in firefox regardless of the folder firefox is installed in

Tags: excel, vba, firefox, hyperlink

I need to make a file to be accessible on multiple devices and on some devices the first code works and on other devices the second code works, can anyone help me please ? Thank you.

```
Sub Data_Week()

Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe " & Range("G12").Value

End Sub

Sub Data_Week()

Shell "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe " & Range("G12").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are the only 2 possible options you want, then you can do it this way:

```
Sub Data_Week()
  Const ff1 As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
  Const ff2 As String = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

  If Len(Dir(ff1)) > 0 Then
    Shell ff1 & " " & Range("G12").Value
  ElseIf Len(Dir(ff2)) > 0 Then
    Shell ff2 & " " & Range("G12").Value
  Else
    MsgBox "firefox not found"
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.